# Ini-File reader with kernel32.dll do not read from file

Tags: vb.net, file, ini

I have the Problem that my script writes only the default value to the new Ini-File. It sould read the value from the BackupConfig. I do not see my error, yet. The output of the MessageBox should be the old URL but it prints google.

I hope you can help me, thank you.

My script looks like this

```
        My.Computer.FileSystem.MoveFile(ConfigName, "backup.Config.ini", True)
        Thread.Sleep(2000)
        Dim Config As IniFile = New IniFile(ConfigName)
        Dim BackupConfig As IniFile = New IniFile("backup.Config.ini")
        MessageBox.Show(BackupConfig.GetString("Window08", "Url", "http://google.de"))

        Config.WriteInteger("Setup", "Opacity", BackupConfig.GetInteger("Setup", "Opacity", 100))
```

This is my IniFile Class, i found it here on Stackoverflow an do not know which user posted it. (Sorry for that)

```
Public Class IniFile
    ' API functions
    Private Declare Ansi Function GetPrivateProfileString _
      Lib "kernel32.dll" Alias "GetPrivateProfileStringA" _
      (ByVal lpApplicationName As String, _
      ByVal lpKeyName As String, ByVal lpDefault As String, _
      ByVal lpReturnedString As System.Text.StringBuilder, _
      ByVal nSize As Integer, ByVal lpFileName As String) _
      As Integer
    Private Declare Ansi Function WritePrivateProfileString _
      Lib "kernel32.dll" Alias "WritePrivateProfileStringA" _
      (ByVal lpApplicationName As String, _
      ByVal lpKeyName As String, ByVal lpString As String, _
      ByVal lpFileName As String) As Integer
    Private Declare Ansi Function GetPrivateProfileInt _
      Lib "kernel32.dll" Alias "GetPrivateProfileIntA" _
      (ByVal lpApplicationName As String, _
      ByVal lpKeyName As String, ByVal nDefault As Integer, _
      ByVal lpFileName As String) As Integer
    Private Declare Ansi Function FlushPrivateProfileString _
      Lib "kernel32.dll" Alias "WritePrivateProfileStringA" _
      (ByVal lpApplicationName As Integer, _
      ByVal lpKeyName As Integer, ByVal lpString As Integer, _
      ByVal lpFileName As String) As Integer
    Dim strFilename As String

    ' Constructor, accepting a filename
    Public Sub New(ByVal Filename As String)
        strFilename = Filename
    End Sub

    ' Read-only filename property
    ReadOnly Property FileName() As String
        Get
            Return strFilename
        End Get
    End Property

    Public Function GetString(ByVal Section As String, _
      ByVal Key As String, ByVal [Default] As String) As String
        ' Returns a string from your INI file
        Dim intCharCount As Integer
        Dim objResult As New System.Text.StringBuilder(256)
        intCharCount = GetPrivateProfileString(Section, Key, _
           [Default], objResult, objResult.Capacity, strFilename)
        If intCharCount > 0 Then GetString = _
           Left(objResult.ToString, intCharCount)
    End Function

    Public Function GetInteger(ByVal Section As String, _
      ByVal Key As String, ByVal [Default] As Integer) As Integer
        ' Returns an integer from your INI file
        Return GetPrivateProfileInt(Section, Key, _
           [Default], strFilename)
    End Function

    Public Function GetBoolean(ByVal Section As String, _
      ByVal Key As String, ByVal [Default] As Boolean) As Boolean
        ' Returns a boolean from your INI file
        Return (GetPrivateProfileInt(Section, Key, _
           CInt([Default]), strFilename) = 1)
    End Function

    Public Sub WriteString(ByVal Section As String, _
      ByVal Key As String, ByVal Value As String)
        ' Writes a string to your INI file
        WritePrivateProfileString(Section, Key, Value, strFilename)
        Flush()
    End Sub

    Public Sub WriteInteger(ByVal Section As String, _
      ByVal Key As String, ByVal Value As Integer)
        ' Writes an integer to your INI file
        WriteString(Section, Key, CStr(Value))
        Flush()
    End Sub

    Public Sub WriteBoolean(ByVal Section As String, _
      ByVal Key As String, ByVal Value As Boolean)
        ' Writes a boolean to your INI file
        WriteString(Section, Key, CStr(CInt(Value)))
        Flush()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Flush()
        ' Stores all the cached changes to your INI file
        FlushPrivateProfileString(0, 0, 0, strFilename)
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Do you have some kind of error handling around the code that Move the current ini file in the backup one? Not specifying the path on the backup could mean that you try to copy the original file into a path where you don't have permission. But this should give an exception of some kind.

Comment: No error message and no exception. Both files are in the same directory with the exe file  (own files).

Comment: The documentation of [FileSystem.MoveFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fh3171xd(v=vs.90).aspx) is confusing. They talk about a _destinationFileName_ but then they explain that this parameter is _Path of the directory into which the file should be moved. Required._ I am not sure what happens on your side, but giving a full file name (IE: D:\temp\backup.config.ini) the code above works as expected

Comment: The file is successfully moved and the new us created. But it does not read from the moved one. I  checked the file with notepad and it looks great. The error must be after that, this is the reason for the sleep. I added this sleep because I thought the file system may be to slow. It didn't help me to add this sleep.